# CUPS lpstat -r Why do some printers show Ready To print while other printers do not show this

Tags: rhel, cups

We use lpstat -p to view all printers that are enabled. I've noticed some printers show as 'Ready to Print' and other printers do not?  All printers show as enabled. We are running RHEL 6.1

[image]

Comment: Because the other printers are not "Ready to Print"? Power-saving sleep? What happens when you print to them?

Comment: I submitted a print job using echo "test" | lp -d Tor-zt230-2 and saw after print job the printer did show as Ready to print.  I think you are right that the printer was probably in a  sleep-mode.  Thanks.